# arduino ethernetClient textFinder

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to read different requests sent by the client. For example: if the request got the "abc=" at URL, execute method A. If the request got the "def=" at the URL execute method B.

Problem is every time I use **client.find("abc")**, the **client** is consumed by the parsing method used by finder lib.

" The parsing is done without using a buffer so there is no way to go back through data that has already been read." says the TextFinder documentation.

So when I try to do **client.find("def")** again, the **client** value stay "empty" and i cant read anymore.

I have already tried to duplicate a variable with the value of the client, but before start the scope of the code, i have to declare "TextFinder finder( client );" and I dont know how to declare again like: "TextFinder finder( client2 );"

Here a example of the code:

```
...
TextFinder finder( client );
...

...
if(client.find("abc=")){
   executeMethodA();
}

if(client.find("def=")){
   executeMethodB()
}
...
```

Any help will be apreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: Where is the library for TextFinder?  Just provide a link so that I can look at it.  Thanks.

Comment: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/TextFinder

Answer (score 0):

To find something in a client, you have to use TextFinder like this :

```
TextFinder finder( client );

if(finder.find("abc=")){
    executeMethodA();
}

if(finder.find("def=")){
    executeMethodB()
}
```

Bye